# PyMC3 Error: AttributeError: 'TheanoConfigParser' object has no attribute 'gcc__cxxflags'

Tags: theano, slurm, pymc3

I'm trying to run PyMC3 on a Slurm cluster. In my code, the following import

`import pymc3 as pm`

raises the following error:

```
 File "/om2/user/rylansch/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymc3/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    __set_compiler_flags()
  File "/om2/user/rylansch/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymc3/__init__.py", line 35, in __set_compiler_flags
    current = theano.config.gcc__cxxflags
AttributeError: 'TheanoConfigParser' object has no attribute 'gcc__cxxflags'
```

What is this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You possibly still have the old `theano` installed. So try uninstalling `theano` and the currently installed pymc3 then install the new version: `theano-pymc`

here's a detailed guide: https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3#installation